# SPI connection with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I wanted to ask. I have A111 pulsed radar sensor and I wanted to use the range message in ros. The connection for the sensor and raspberry pi are thru SPI. How can I connect the SPI with ros? I'm using ROS noetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391780/spi-connection-with-ros/) by [Nur92](https://answers.ros.org/users/88172/nur92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @Nur92,

> The connection for the sensor and raspberry pi are thru SPI

Just imagine you are getting data off your SPI to any programming language (Python or C++), and then you can directly create `msgs` according to your requirement, or you can use the [radar_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/radar_msgs) package and publish that message.

You can use that published message to any other nodes by subscribing to it.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1